# DataFrame>Replacing part of a string to blank ,a string which includes alphabets and signs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi i need to replace a string,'Manik+/India/IAM/" from the data in my column ID of data frame df.
I need to replace this string with blank, i.e. nothing.

df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.replace('Manik+/India/IAM/', '') doesnt work because i believe the thing i want to replace has both letters and +/.

what is the best way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have "something, then `/`, then the numerical ID", use `rsplit`:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.rsplit('/', n=1).str[-1]
```

Else, ensure you're not using a regex as `+` has a special meaning in regex:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.replace('Manik+/India/IAM/', '', regex=False)
```

Comment: @BigBen your link did not mention the rsplit alternative, which I think is much better adapted here

Comment: @BigBen added to the list ;)